# Cannot change Jest mock function behavior

Tags: typescript, react-native, redux, jestjs, enzyme

The situation I am having issue with is this:

1.) Setup mocks in beforeEach

2.) Try to change some of the mock behavior in individual tests where it needs to be more unique

3.) I cannot change the values from what I setup in #1

This is partially pseudo code, so syntax might be off, as I don't have the source in front of me:

```js
import Module from '../module';

...

jest.mock('../module');

describe('test suite', {

let mockFn = undefined;

beforeEach(() => {
   mockFn = jest.fn(() => 'banana');
   Module.function = mockFn;
});

test('happy test', () => {
   // this test needs Module.function to return 'banana', so it doesn't 
   // have any issues, as calls to Module.function return 'banana'
});

test('test with issue', () => {
   let mockFn2 = jest.fn(() => 'new value to return instead of banana');

   Module.function = mockFn2;

   //execute code
   //calls to Module.function still return 'banana'
});
}
```

I've tried some things such as adding an afterEach function that calls mockFn.mockClear(). I haven't been able to override the original mock function. For most of my tests the original mocks are fine because I want a default value but a few of my tests I need to make sure the code reacts a certain way when certain values are returned by these functions but I cannot change it from whatever I assign to it as the first mock function.

Edit - Here's how it's used:

```js
function() {
...

  if(Module.function().includes('somevalue'){
     //Do something
  }
  else {
     fetch(Module.function() + other stuff... )
     ...
}

};
```

Here's how it's defined:

```js
export default class Module {

   public static function() {
      ...
   }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: It depends on how `Module` is imported and used in the code under test, can you update the question with the code you are testing?

Comment: @brian-lives-outdoors no, I cannot post the source. I'll update the OP with pseudo code of how it's used.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. Not a terribly interesting solution. I just realized that I had put all of the logic to change the mocks... after calling the function under test. Whoopsies. I think I spent two hours trying different ways to reset the mocks without realizing that...